# how to write a switch in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, switch-statement

I'm working on asp.net and c# to create 1 application in which I'm facing a problem.the problem is.

I have 3 link buttons named on a single page.

1. category
2. location
3. username

That page also includes one TextBox through which I'm searching the users by category and all. I have created web services for searching the users by category,name and location.

But what I want is when I click on link button category, only category web service will be called not other 2 similarly for others.

Comment: please do show us what you've done so far so that we can assist you.

Comment: You should implement 3 methods that handles the query. (every linkbutton should have it's own handler) No switch involves here.

Answer (score 1):

When a user clicks on the specific button, you need to send the request to another function.

```
public function void catagory_click()
{
   Getservice("Cat");
}
public function void location_click()
{
   Getservice("Loc");
}
public function void username_click()
{
   Getservice("Usr");
}

function void Getservice(string _selButton)
{
    switch(_selButton)
    {
        case 'Cat': 
        // call catagory webservice
        break;
        case 'Loc': 
        // call Location webservice
        break;
        case 'Usr': 
        // call Username webservice
        break;
        default : 
        //call default service
    }
}
```

Reference: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/switch_statement_in_csharp.htm